# How do I display data in the browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to map through information in a rest api, I receive the request just fine, but when I try to display the data in JSX nothing shows up.

This is the file where I make the request:

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";
import ShowcaseMap from "./ShowcaseMap";

const Showcase = () => {
  const results = [];

  useEffect(() => {

    const getProducts = () => {
        fetch(
          "https://kohls.p.rapidapi.com/products/list?limit=30&offset=1",
          {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
              "x-rapidapi-key": process.env.REACT_APP_SECRET,
              "x-rapidapi-host": "kohls.p.rapidapi.com",
            },
          }
        )
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .catch(error => console.error(error))
      };
    getProducts();
  }, []);
  return (
    <ul>
      {results.map((result) => (
        <li>
            <ShowcaseMap
                key={result.webId}
                productTitle={result.productTitle}
            />
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default Showcase;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

And this is the file that returns the JSX:

```js
const ShowcaseMap = ({productTitle}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{productTitle}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ShowcaseMap
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

When I make the request I want to return a list in the browser, but nothing is showing up.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're not updating the value of `results`.

When you set `const results = [];`, that value of `results` stays the same for the entire duration even after the fetch call is made because you're not updating it at any time.

What you want to do since this is a function component, is to turn the `results` array into a state driven value.  One way of doing that is to use the [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook, you can reference that hook from react's docs.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"; // <-- import useState
// ... other imports

const Showcase = () => {
  const [results, setResults ] = useState([]); // <-- use `useState` here

// ... rest of React component
```

This lets you update the state of results in a way that will trigger the rerendering of your components.

Now what you have to do is actually `setResults` somewhere down the line, or else results will never update with new values.  That would be when your promise resolves in your `getProducts` function with the `data` values:

```
    const getProducts = () => {
        fetch(/* ...fetch arguments ...*/)
        .then(/* ...first .then function */)
        .then(data => {
           console.log(data);
           setResults(data); // <-- call `setResults` to set the value contained in `data` to your `results` state
         })
```

Now when your `getProducts` function runs, its will set a new value of `results` when your data is fetched and all children will be passed the new prop values when result changes.

Here is what the full code will look like in case there is any confusion:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ShowcaseMap from "./ShowcaseMap";

const Showcase = () => {
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const getProducts = () => {
        fetch(
          "https://kohls.p.rapidapi.com/products/list?limit=30&offset=1",
          {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
              "x-rapidapi-key": process.env.REACT_APP_SECRET,
              "x-rapidapi-host": "kohls.p.rapidapi.com",
            },
          }
        )
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => setResults(data))
        .catch(error => console.error(error))
      };
    getProducts();
  }, []);
  return (
    <ul>
      {results.map((result) => (
        <li>
            <ShowcaseMap
                key={result.webId}
                productTitle={result.productTitle}
            />
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default Showcase;
```

Comment: "a functional component" — Not a functional component; it has state, so it has side effects, so it isn't [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming). It is a [function component](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#hooks-and-function-components).

Comment: @Quentin technically you're right.  Thanks for the correction.  Terminology wise, most of the community refers to them as "functional components" from articles I have read, so I use the colloquial term that is used elsewhere.  But yes, by technicality you're right, it is not "functional" by right of "functional programming".  But that doesn't change the natural language that has evolved in the community.